# Subset data frame by rows containing the system date

Tags: r

I would like to subset a data frame by selecting only the rows with the current system date.

For example, I have this data frame:

```
df = data.frame("var" = c("A", "A", "B", "B"),
                "date" = c("2020-03-01", "2020-03-17",
                           "2020-03-01", "2020-03-17"))
df$date = as.POSIXct(df$date, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
```

If today is 2020-03-17, I would like to subset the rows that contain only the current date.

I have tried the following:

```
df_today = df[which(df$date == Sys.Date()),]
```

Which gives the error:

> Warning message: In which(df$date == Sys.Date()) :
>
> Incompatible methods ("Ops.POSIXt", "Ops.Date") for "=="

I have also tried:

```
df[which(df$date == as.POSIXct(Sys.Date())),]
```

Which returns an empty data frame. What I found works is if I coerce the `date` column as a character and then subset the rows in this way:

```
df$date = as.character(df$date)
df[which(df$date == as.character(Sys.Date)),]
```

This can work, but I would like to know where I am going wrong with my my previous attempts and if there is a better way than converting back and forth between character and POSIXct?

Thank you in advance for any input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class `"Date"` is not the same as class `"POSIXct"`, you need to convert first to the former using local `Sys.timezone()`.

```
df[as.Date(df$date, tz=Sys.timezone()) == Sys.Date(),]
#   var       date
# 2   A 2020-03-17
# 4   B 2020-03-17
```

---

*Data used*

```
df <- structure(list(var = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("A", 
"B"), class = "factor"), date = structure(c(1583017200, 1584399600, 
1583017200, 1584399600), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "")), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: For some reason this still returns an empty object for me.

Comment: @tlmoore The reason for this is the local time zone, which must be taken into account. See edit.

Comment: Oh wow, I'm an idiot! Thank you for pointing this out. By it's nature the data is one day behind. Of course I can't sort by the current date. Now I just need to subset by the system date minus one day. Thanks again for the realization.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)
df$date = as.Date(df$date, format = "%Y-%m-%d")

df %>% filter(date==Sys.Date())
```

Comment: It is still returning an empty object. I'm not sure if there is something I'm fundamentally missing here. I'm pulling the data from multiple .csv files and combining into one big data frame. This is done using `reshape2::melt()`. Next I have to re-format the `date` column because it has the format "X%m.%d.%y", which I do in this way:
`as.POSIXct(gsub(x = df$date, 
                             pattern = "X", replacement = "", 
                             fixed = TRUE), format = "%m.%d.%y")`. I'm not sure if this is causing the problem...